# CalendarView in Android not showing correct month

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have implemented CalendarView in my Android App. I have a strange issue on selection of the date. The month is showing April 2015 in the top but the toast is showing 1/3/2015? If I Scroll May 2015 the toast shows 1/4/2015. The month is always a previous month.

I am doing something like this:

```
calendar =(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarforstart);
calendar.setShowWeekNumber(false);
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), day + "/" + month + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Please check the snapshot:

[image]

Did you notice in the top it shows April 2015 but the below the toast shows 1/3/2015.. Why is this happening?

Can anybody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Month start with 0. so `jan-dec` is like `0-11`

you need to change it to `month+1`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), day + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This is how Calendar Class works. Check: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: By the way... if this worked great, you should accept the answer.

Comment: @TheDevMan cool.. accept the answer so it can help others to refer this